# Reset Form, Reset Field Value, Reset Focus All onSubmit()

Tags: javascript, forms

Earlier I found a solution to a problem I didn't have and now I have created more problems in hopes of finding a solution.

I have a form that submits a URL:

```
<form name="urlField" onsubmit="return submitURLFieldForm();">
  <input type="text" name="address" id="addressfield" />
</form>
```

That URL is opened in a new tab/window. Now I'd like the field to be reset, the "http://" to be added back and the focus to be at the end, ready to type in a new URL. My JS below works in all browsers except Opera. Since the page loads correctly in all browsers INCLUDING Opera (the field `focus()` & `value()` are both originally set in the `<body>` tag) I'm thinking it must be a problem with my onSubmit function below:

```
function submitURLFieldForm() {
var url = document.getElementById('addressfield').value;
if (!url.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+:\/\//)) {
    url = 'http://' + url;
}
window.open(url);
    document.urlField.address.reset();
    document.urlField.address.focus();
    document.urlField.address.value='http\://';
}
```

Is there another way of writing this? Is this sloppy?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. On submit you are trying to open a new page with the same form but all values reset?

Comment: If it is not working in Opera check the javascript debugger. What does it say?

Comment: onSubmit I am trying to open a new tab/window with the URL that was provided (that part works) but then clear the text that was entered, replace the "http://" and put the focus back at the end so that when the visitor goes back to the original tab where they made the submission they are greeted with a "new" form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitURLFieldForm() {
    var url = document.getElementById('addressfield').value;
    if (!url.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+:\/\//)) {
        url = 'http://' + url;
    }
    window.open(url);
    document.getElementsByName('urlField')[0].reset();
    resetForm();
    return false;
}
window.onload = function() {
    resetForm();
}
function resetForm() {
    var address = document.getElementsByName('address')[0];
    address.focus();
    address.value = "http://";
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form name="urlField" onsubmit="return submitURLFieldForm();">
      <input type="text" name="address" id="addressfield" />
    </form> 
</body>
```

**EDIT**
After checking opera console, added some changes. I hope it works as you think.

Comment: that works in all browsers just like my OP but not in Opera. in Opera the field is reset, the "http://" is put back but the there is no focus at the end. again, since it works when the page is originally loaded maybe I should scrap the extra reset, focus & value JS and just reload the page? I'm trying to get that to work right now...

Comment: We have a winner! That's involved. Why so many hoops just to please Opera?! Thank you - this rocks!